# How to copy Excel range including the charts and graphs and paste it as a single image?

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA, I can copy and paste an Excel range to outlook as an image or as an HTML table. I can also copy and paste a single chart/graph from Excel into Outlook as an image. Now, I have this Excel sheet that has multiple tables and charts. I would like to be able to copy and paste all tables and charts from the excel sheet into Outlook as a single image using VBA. Is there a way to do that? It would be like copying everything that's on the selected range including the charts and graphs overlaid on top of it into outlook using VBA.

Comment: What code are you using which isn't working as you'd like? Did you select the range and use `Selection.CopyPicture  Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap`? Alternatively `Worksheets("SheetName"),Range("A1:J20").CopyPicture  Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap`

Answer (score 1):

The lines of code posted below worked for me. I was trying to create an auto-mailer for a report that my team sends every hour. To decrease their time spent on running, copying, and pasting the report on Outlook, I automated most of the processes involved in the report. The question that I posted here on stackoverflow (thanks @Levon for the edit) was the problem I ran into. It's incredible what you can learn by running the Record Macro function in Excel. I recorded the actions from range selection, copying, and pasting as picture on Excel and that's how I got the necessary codes needed to solve the problem.

```
Dim xOutlook As Object, _
    xEmail As Object, _
    xInspector As Object, _
    wEditor As Object, _
    lastRow As Long, _
    pic As Picture

Sheets("Report").Select

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(lastRow, 23)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Report").Range("AJ1").Select
Sheets("Report").Pictures.Paste.Select

Set pic = Selection

pic.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
pic.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.9, msoTrue
pic.Copy

Set xOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xEmail = xOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set xInspector = xEmail.GetInspector
Set wEditor = xInspector.WordEditor

With xEmail
    .Display
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Test"
    .Body = "" & vbCrLf
    wEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
    wEditor.Application.Selection.End = wEditor.Application.Selection.Start
    wEditor.Application.Selection.Paste
    pic.Delete
End With
```